# San Disk Cruzer 16G USB detected as local disk

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, removable-media

I have a SanDisk 16G pen drive.

It is not being detected as Removable drive but as a Local disk.

I have tried formatting it with FAT32 but it didn't work.

How do I change it back so that it is being detected as Removable Media?

Comment: "I have tried formatting it with fat32 but it didn't work." How, precisely, did you try? What went wrong? And -- why do you care? What difference does it make?

Answer (score 2):

Follow this [link](http://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/12830/%7E/flash-drive-shows-as-hard-disk-drive-%28fixed-disk%29-in-windows-explorer), it is a SanDisk support page that answers your question:

> Historically, flash drives have been configured as removable disks and Windows Explorer displays them as 'Removable Media'. Windows 8 Certification requires flash drive manufacturers to configure flash drives as fixed disks. Flash drives configured as fixed disk will show up in Windows Explorer as 'Hard Disk Drives'. Flash drives configured as fixed disks still function the same as those configured as removable disks.
>
> You can still connect and disconnect the flash drives from the USB port without having to power off the computer. You can also still use the 'Safely Remove Hardware' feature when disconnecting.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. Please include all relevant information in your post. It's okay to link solutions posted here on Stack Exchange and on other websites, but generally it's good to quote and paraphrase the solution here as well. Please see our [help center](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information about writing good answers.